# Vagrant not working, server not found

Tags: docker, vagrant, windows-10

Am working on setting up vagrant in windows 10

When i execute the command vagrant up am getting this error: -

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /vagrant/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

My vagrant File:--

```
#run a docker image
    user.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
        d.build_image "/vagrant", args: "-t my-php-apache-image"
        d.run "my-php-apache-image", args: " -p 8080:80 -v /vagrant:/var/www/html"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
```

There is an "app" folder which has a simple echo hello world command in vagrant root .Last day it was working file but not working now.I didnt change anything i run the same commmand , vagrant up

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like your Vagrant are unable to locate the `Dockerfile` are you sure in the same directory ..? another option if you're using windows is to use `txt` format for `Dockerfile` i.e `docker build -t my-php-apache-image -f ./Dockerfile.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, well I just want to know.. once we did vagrant up for a particular project and able to view the output in the browser (suppose a PHP / MySQL web application).Can we access the same output by just running the same command vagrant up right? or do we need to change/remove/alter anything?
What i do is open virtual box,
Go to project root and do vagrant up in command line.
enough right?

Comment: im not quite sure understand what you mean,,, but as far as i know, if you change something in vagrant that already up and running, you dont necessarily need to issue command `vagrant up` again, instead use provisioning, like `vagrant provision [vm-name]` .. anyway.. where did you put the `Dockerfile` ..?

Comment: Dockerfile is in root folder.What i mean is suppose if i shutdown my local machine (windows 10)where vagrant is running and the next day i switch on my machine what steps should i take to run my project? 

Turn on Virtualbox manager and got to project root and run vagrant up.. right?

Comment: yes.. thats pretty much it. . it seems like an issue . .have you tried this workaround.. in **(plugins/providers/docker/action/build.rb, line 46)**
change the line 

`args.push("--file=\"#{dockerfile_path}\"")`

 to

 `args.push("--file=#{dockerfile_path}")`


this is the discussion regarding the issue : https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/7914